# mvc2 dropdownlist datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner in programming entity framework MS

I have two entities "Dossiers" and "clients"
for the client entity I managed to "model" & "controller" and list and creates and delete.
and I would like to do the same thing with "folders" knowing that each file belongs to a "clients" relationship is then:
(dosiers.dos_CL_N = clienst.CL_N)
I find it difficult to use "DropDownList" in the page file creation
thank you for your help in advance
Here is my asp code
**Create.aspx**

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
            <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Fields</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOS_N) %>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DOS_N) %>
                    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOS_N) %>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                     <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOS_CL_N) %>
                </div>
                 <div class="editor-field">    
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ClientDropDownList" runat="server" 
                        DataSourceID="ClientDataSource" DataTextField="CL_NOM" DataValueField="CL_N"
                        AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="ClientDataSource" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="name=ClientsManagerDBEntities" 
                        DefaultContainerName="ClientsManagerDBEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
                        EntitySetName="Clients" EntityTypeFilter="Clients" 
                        Select="it.[CL_N], it.[CL_NOM]">
                    </asp:EntityDataSource>
     </div>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>

        <% } %>

        <div>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "DossiersList")%>
        </div>
```

**DossierController.cs**

```
....
...
 // GET: /DossiersManager/Dossier/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /DossiersManager/Contact/Create

         [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] Dossiers DossierToCreate)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View();

            try
            {
                _entities.AddToDossiers(DossierToCreate);
                _entities.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("DossiersList");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
...
..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for all
I found the solution
I added this code in DossierController.cs

```
private DossiersDBEntities DossiersDb=new DossiersDBEntities();
private ClientsDBEntities ClientsDb = new ClientsDBEntities();
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var ListClients = from c in ClientsDb.Clients
                            select new
                            {
                                c.CL_N,
                                c.CL_NOM
                            };
            ViewData["ListClients"] = new SelectList(ListClients, "CL_N", "CL_NOM");
            return View();
```

and I change the way in my asp page create

```
    <div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.DropDownList("DOS_CL_N", (SelectList)ViewData["ListClients"])%>  
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOS_CL_N) %>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The asp:DropDownList is ASP.NET, not ASP.NET MVC. For MVC, you have Html.DropDownList, for which you load the entities in the controller, not the view.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Html.DropDownListFor` helpers instead of asp controls,

**View:**

```
<%Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.YourProperty, (SelectList)ViewBag.ListValues)%>
```

**Contoller:**

```
List<SelectListItem> DropDownList = new List<SelectListItem>();
DropDownList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "text 1"});
DropDownList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "text 2"});

ViewBag.ListValues= new SelectList(DropDownList, "Value", "Text");
```

Comment: mvc2 viewbag not exist

Comment: sorry, use `ViewData` if you are using MVC 2..!